# Using PHP with Miva Mechant shopping cart

Tags: php

I am currently altering a clients Miva website and adding some custom logic. The problems is I have recently found out that Miva does not execute PHP and that is clearly what I need it to do. Any suggestions on a work around so all this PhP logic I created doesnt go wasted.

Answer (score 0):

Some MIVA installations allow for MySQL database use over MIVASQL database files. If you can convert your MIVA store to that db, you can then use your PHP code to manipulate/find your records.